# Firebase global variable Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, firebase, nomethoderror

https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby

How do I use firebase across methods and not locally as shown in the examples? Ex: `@firebase`, See the paste at --
http://bpaste.net/show/501b6a67c8d4

or --

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'firebase'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

# Configure database
configure do
  @base_uri = 'https://veriyo.firebaseio.com/'
  @firebase = Firebase::Client.new(@base_uri)
end

# Display homepage
get '/' do
  erb :index
end

post '/search' do
  @username = params["username"]
  redirect to("/user/#{@username}")
end

get '/user/:username' do
  response = @firebase.push("todos", { :name => @username })
  'hello'
end
```

The @firebase variable's attributes aren't accessible there -- `#<NoMethodError: undefined method`push' for nil:NilClass>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set them as constants:

```
FB_Base_uri = 'https://veriyo.firebaseio.com/'
FB_Firebase = Firebase::Client.new(FB_Base_uri)
```

Comment: How can I use @base_uri if it's initialized as `Base_uri`?

Comment: You'll use Base_uri instead of @base_uri :)

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/3f8009d3202d errors at `#<TypeError: #<Firebase::Client:[xxxxxxxxxxx] @request=#<Firebase::Request:[xxxxxxxxxx] @base_uri="https://veriyo.firebaseio.com/">, @auth=nil> is not a class/module>`

Comment: I changed some of the keys and generated values to something resembling `xxxxxx` btw :)

Comment: Ahh. I think we're having an issue because Firebase is already defined in the gem. Try prefacing the constants with FB_ per my edit.

Comment: If you get another error, could you paste the full output in a bpaste?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60654/discussion-between-joel-brewer-and-tejas-manohar).